# Human Detection using Hog descriptors using opencv in java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have successfully read the video from webcam using opencv. Now i want to 
detect humans from webcam using Hogdescriptors. I have read many opencv tutorials but could not get anything from it and not able to implement it,can any one help me to implement this in java? I am attaching my java code which captures video from webcam.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;


public class JavaCam extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private DaemonThread myThread = null;
    int count = 0;
    VideoCapture webSource = null;

    Mat frame = new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();


    class DaemonThread implements Runnable
    {
    protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

    @Override
    public  void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(runnable)
            {
                if(webSource.grab())
                {
                try
                        {
                            webSource.retrieve(frame);
                Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

                BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                Graphics g=jPanel1.getGraphics();

                if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null))

                if(runnable == false)
                            {
                    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                    this.wait();
                }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
                         {
                System.out.println("Error");
                         }
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }


    public JavaCam() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(320, 240));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 422, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 342, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setText("start");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("pause");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 422, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(60, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(111, 111, 111)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(126, 126, 126))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        webSource =new VideoCapture(0);
        myThread = new DaemonThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.runnable = true;
        t.start();
        jButton1.setEnabled(false);  //start button
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);  // stop button
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        myThread.runnable = false;
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);   
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);

        webSource.release();            

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); // load native library of opencv

        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaCam.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaCam.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaCam.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaCam.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JavaCam().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: "I have read many opencv tutorials but could not get anything from it " If you're not able to understand any tutorials how exactly do you expect to solve this problem with our help?

Comment: I mean to say i read about HogDescriptors and SVM classifiers but i dont know how to implement them in a java program.@Piglet

Comment: that's a bit too broad for this community. I mean teaching you this would take how many pages of text? break your problem down into atomic sub-problems and then ask questions about the first thing you cannot solve